# ember js get relationships of relationships

Tags: ember.js

My routes have something like this

```
return this.store.query('author', {filter:{username : username},
            include: 'books, books.readers'})
```

as we can see author has Many-2-Many relationships with books, book have relationship with reader

How can I include books.reader when run query with author?

Comment: what does your current query return? It seams like each book in books would have a list of readers, so finding one reader from books (as shown) doesn't make sense.

Comment: ok let me edit, it should return author with books that include all that book's reader

Answer (score 0):

Ember Data provides the ability to query for records that meet certain criteria. Calling store.query() will make a GET request with the passed object serialized as query params. This method returns a DS.PromiseArray in the same way as findAll.

So for example in your case `author` with `:username` can be changed to the following code:

```
// GET to /persons?filter[username]=username
this.get('store').query('author', {
  filter: {
    username: username
  }
}).then(function(username) {
  // Do something with `username` which can be another filter and whatever else you want, give it a try.
});
```

Hope it can solve your problem.